# How to save PHP array in database by converting array into JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Here is a my PHP array. I want to convert it into JSON. after a converting to JSON. than after I want to save it in database how can I achieve this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6:30pm
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 8:00pm
    [1] => 
)
```

Comment: use `json_encode`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert this Array into JSon in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255954/how-to-convert-this-array-into-json-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to store json in the database, you can use `json_encode` and `json_decode`.

Comment: Why wouldn't he store json in database? It was always OK but now has even more sense: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: you kidding, ain't you?

Comment: @jakubwrona why would i be kidding?

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode()` - Returns the JSON representation of a value.

Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.

A numerically indexed PHP array is translated to an array literal in the JSON string. A `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option can be used if you want the array to be output as an object instead:

**Example One:**

```
<?php
$ar = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry');
echo json_encode($ar,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); 
?>
```

**Output:**

```
{"0":"apple","1":"orange","2":"banana","3":"strawberry"}
```

**Example Two:**

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

> After you need to fetch the data you need `json_decode()` and it follows as this.

`json_decode()` — Decodes a JSON string

Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
?>
```

**Output:**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this the `json_encode($array)` and it will gives you a json string,than you can save it to a row.